# Can I make a Dapp in react that doesn't uses metamask at all?

Tags: web3js, metamask, ethers.js, react

I want to build a Dapp in which I don't want to use the metamask wallet. There is a central ethereum address that I have and when any one calls the function that intracts with the blockchain I want that the gas fee to be deducted from that wallet in the backend and this should happen without the need of user confirming the transaction from the frontend. Which libraries should I use to perform this? Please guide me!

Comment: Like the tags in your question: use either web3js or ethersjs if you use nodejs for backend

Answer (score 2):

this is awesome to onboard new users into web3.
You can use Gelato Relay https://docs.gelato.network/developer-services/relay which allows you to send transactions via a normal HTTP post to the blockchain. You can use the [1balance](https://docs.gelato.network/developer-services/relay/payment-and-fees/1balance) to pay for all transactions.

Hope it helps!